# openni "creating depth generator failed"

Tags: kinect, openni, openni-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I just installed the diamondback base and openni_kinect package. Then, if I do

rosmake openni_camera everything was compiled successfully. Then, if I do roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch, it says

[ INFO] [1310405330.895508189]: [/openni_node1] Number devices connected:

> 1
> [ INFO] [1310405330.895790349]: [/openni_node1] 1. device on bus 002:06 is
> a Xbox NUI Camera (2ae) from Microsoft (45e) with serial id
> 'B00363708464051B'
> [ INFO] [1310405330.900782094]: [/openni_node1] searching for device with
> index = 1 [ INFO] [1310405334.914925388]: [/openni_node1] No matching
> device found.... waiting for devices. Reason:
> openni_wrapper::OpenNIDevice::OpenNIDevice(xn::Context&, const
> xn::NodeInfo&, const xn::NodeInfo&, const xn::NodeInfo&) @
> /tmp/buildd/ros-diamondback-openni-kinect-0.2.1/debian/ros-diamondback-ope
> nni-kinect/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/openni_kinect/openni_camera/src/ope
> nni_device.cpp @ 59 : creating depth generator failed. Reason: Got a
> timeout while waiting for a network command to complete!

like above.

I don't know how to solve this problem,

Can anybody help me with installing openni_kinect and what my problem is???

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10565/openni-%22creating-depth-generator-failed%22/) by [monkey90](https://answers.ros.org/users/821/monkey90/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-07-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-07-11**:
replug the device and then post the output of "dmesg" and "lsusb".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

no activity > 1 month, closing

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0